# How can I get Cargo to tell me what content is out of date when building with --locked?

Tags: rust, dependency-management, rust-cargo

When building via `cargo --locked test`, if the Cargo.lock file is out of date you'll get the message:

```
error: the lock file /home/.../Cargo.lock needs to be updated but --locked was passed to prevent this
```

Adding `--verbose` doesn't yield any additional information.

Answer (score 1):

I would:

1. Perform a build without `--locked`
2. Diff the changed Cargo.lock to the one saved in source control.

I might also try a tool like [cargo outdated](https://github.com/kbknapp/cargo-outdated), but this will show all the dependencies that are out of date, not just mismatches between Cargo.toml and Cargo.lock.

Comment: It looks like `cargo-outdated` just automates the manual hack?

Comment: @jhfrontz no, I don't think so. They are slightly different usecases that might happen to overlap in certain situations. `cargo outdated` is supposed to tell you when the versions you have aren't the newest possible. Presumably, there are cases where the Cargo.toml and Cargo.lock are out-of-sync but you already have the newest version.